# Injecting a list of SpringBoot Custom Configuration Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, lombok

I'm trying to inject a list of custom Config Properties that I created in my application.properties file into a Controller. I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.resource' in value "#{${custom.resource}}"` I have also tried injecting it as follows: `@Value("${custom.resource}"`

Here is my ConfigurationProperty class:
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

```
import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Data
    public static class Resource {

        private String description;

        private String category;

        private String URL;

        private Boolean PDF;
    }
}
```

My getter and setter methods are generated by Lombok

here is how I have my properties laid out:

```
custom.resource.description[6]=Description
custom.resource.category[6]=the-category
custom.resource.url[6]=somelink.com
custom.resource.pdf[6]=false

custom.resource.description[7]=Description
custom.resource.category[7]=the-category
custom.resource.url[7]=somelink.com
custom.resource.pdf[7]=false
```

I am not sure if what I am doing is just not possible and if there is another way I should be going about it or what. Any guidance would be great

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your class as following:

```
@Getter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private final Resource resource = new Resource();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Resource {

        private List<String> description = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> category = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> URL = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Boolean> PDF = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

[The source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

Comment: Getting a compilation error on the `private final resource = new Resource();` "`final, float expected`" and Don't I need the Configuration and ConfigurationProperties annotation?

Comment: I am still getting the same IllegalArgument exception

Comment: @ebraun99 It seems you need a list of every property - I added this to the answer... Regarding exception - how do you read the properties?

Comment: I'm reading the properties using a Value I think the correct syntax for a list is `@Value("${custom.resource}")` but I have been trying both that and `@Value("#{${custom.resource}}")` but still no change with the addition of the lists. To clarify, each Resource should have one of each property though. I am wanting to get a List of Resources out of my application.properties file. Should my square brackets be moved to the right of resource?

Comment: @ebraun99 if you are going to read properties using `@Value` (`@Value("${custom.resource}")` - is correct syntax) then you don't have to create a property class - just add them to your `application.properties`. Class is useful for type-safing or validating the parameters. Try to read the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) carefully - I'm sure you'll solve your issue.

Comment: The whole reason I am using a class is so that I can pull my list of 7 "Resource" all into my Model with one @Value property, which to my understanding isn't possible when just including in the properties file

Comment: @ebraun99 if you need to work with 'list' of `Reource`s - you need use the `List<Resource>` )). Try this code: `@Value("${custom.resource}")  private List<Resource> resources;` with properties in `application.properties`: `custom.resources[1].description=...` (without the properties class)

Comment: It seems as though Spring doesn't know how to resolve it with the list within another property. Still getting the IllegalArgument Exception

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. Will update with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in order to solve this I needed to add a ResourceList to the ConfigProperty class as well as call the list by bean name in the `@Value` using spring EL

```
import java.util.List;
```

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

```
import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("custom")
@Data
public class ConfigProperties {

    private List<Resource> resourceList;

    @Data
    public static class Resource {

        private String description;

        private String category;

        public String url;

        public Boolean pdf;
    }
}
```

`@Value("#{configProperties.resourceList}")` included in my Controller class

to anyone wondering I did this by looking at the Application Context bean names in a test

Answer (score 0):

I am using many prefixes to separate mi configuration properties as mention at [Guide to @ConfigurationProperties](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#bean) (IMHO is more elegant).

Following the official documentation described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge). You need to change your properties file as:

```
custom.resource[6].description=Description
custom.resource[6].category=the-category
custom.resource[6].url=somelink.com
custom.resource[6].pdf=false

custom.resource[7].description=Description
custom.resource[7].category=the-category
custom.resource[7].url=somelink.com
custom.resource[7].pdf=false
```

Also you need to create a POJO to manage the information as follow:

```
public class Resource {
    private String description;
    private String category;
    private String url
    private boolean pdf

    /**
    * Setters and getters
    */
}
```

And finally add the class to manage properly the Configuration properties:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private final List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom.resource")
    public List<Resource> resources() {
        return this.resources;
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
@Autowired
private ConfigProperties config;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    for (Resource resource : config.resources()) {
        // More lines of code
    }
}
```